# Can an LG G3 ROM be used for LG G3 Vigor?

Tags: custom-roms, lg-g3-vigor

Can an LG G3 ROM be used on LG G3 Vigor? I would like to know if it will work because my friend would like to flash a ROM on his phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time, the answer is it depends on which ROM are you talking about. Most ROMs comes with a speficic set of devices in mind (due to the need and support of partition layout, hardware-specific drivers, etc), so it really depends on the developer.

In most cases, a really similar hardware, would indicate that it should be usable to some extent.